# Java, XML, or both?

Tags: java, android, xml

For Android app development would it be wise to use only Java, only XML, or a mixture of the two? Which option would you say is easiest or the most efficient? There seems to be more resources for Java so perhaps it would be a better option to use straight Java, but I dunno if I will be losing on out any functionality provided by XML.

Comment: In what context? Android?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, Android app development

Comment: Get off the grass mods, Appu answered perfectly with all the information I need, 'good answers would be too long for this format' honestly....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to use both. You can completely develop only using `java`, but I don't think it would be possible only with `xml`. Because with the help of xml you can define layouts, but you cannot control the functionality of the controls. So, at that point of time java comes into picture. XML provides you a structure based and easy way of implementing `UI` and `java` provides the way of controlling and functionality for the application.

Comment: So, XML handles the GUI and Java does the behind the scenes functionality.

Comment: Yes, but you can use java too for the GUI, but that turns out to be very complex as your layout structure becomes lengthy.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah I did notice that XML is rather basic for adding objects, can make text fields and buttons with one line, trouble is getting things to work xP anyway thanks for the answer, I'll just have to keep slugging on to figure it out x.x

Answer (score 0):

You have to use both. XML will be used for structuring the layouts of each screen. Java will pretty much be used for everything else, including ways reference and alter the functionality of the xml files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use both. Java for controller and almost XML for layout(View, dimen, color, string)

Besides, the advantage of XML is use can easily support multiscreen devices and multi-languages as well.

For support multiscreens: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html